# Choose the valid methods for navigating to a fragment identifier

Tags: html

What are the valid methods for navigating to a fragment identifier ? What are the detail of fragment identifier and their use in HTML5. Could anybody explain in brief.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Answer (score 0):

So basically you have all you need to know about fragment identifiers [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) but in short, the way you want to navigate to a fragment identifier is as follows:

```
<a href="#E2">Go to episode 2</a>
.
.
.
<div id="E2"> ...... </div>
```